# How to Loop Input video x number of time using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to loop same video 4 times and output as video using ffmpeg.
SO I create code like this in ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -loop 4 -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
```

but when i run it it give the error like this.

```
Option Loop Not Found.
```

how to do this withour error. Please Help Me

Answer (score 13):

<s>In recent versions, it's</s>

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop 4 -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
```

Due to a bug, the above does not work with MP4s. But if you wrap to a MKV, it works for me.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mkv
```

then,

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop 4 -i output.mkv -c copy output.mp4
```

Comment: This does not work. The video plays once, then it stays silent and only repeats the last .5 seconds occasionally

Comment: Yeah, there's a [bug](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5719) when working with MP4s. Added workaround.

Comment: Thanks, but this still does not work for me. Slightly different results: The video plays once, then repeats random bits of video or audio. Weired. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Which player is this?

Comment: I tried various players on ubuntu (VLC, Totem, etc). But this finally worked for me: http://video.stackexchange.com/a/12906 Thanks for your help though

Comment: @Gyan -stream_loop audio input  is not working while replacing audio directly in mapping. ,help me

Comment: Original answer works in modern builds now.

Answer (score 2):

I've found an equivalent work-around [with input concatenation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) for outdated/bugged versions -stream_loop:

`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "video-source.txt" -f concat -safe 0 -i "audio-source.txt" -c copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -fflags +genpts -t 10:00:00.0 /path/to/output.ext`

This will loop video and audio independently of each other and force-stop the output at 10 hour mark.

Both text files consist of

```
file '/path/to/file.ext'
```

but you must make sure to repeat this line enough times to keep the output satisfied.

For example, if your total video time is less than total audio time then video output will stop earlier than intended and the audio will keep playing until either -t 10H is reached or audio ends prematurely.